# Determine whether argument is valid

Tags: logic

**Question:** 
Determine whether the argument is valid.

Not all dogs bark. Some animals that don't bark have tails. So some dogs have tails.

**Answer:** The argument is not valid.

I am confused on where I went wrong for my steps below which led me to a valid statement. I am new to Latex so I couldn't figure out how to clearly add the reasoning for each step after I completed it. Although it should be relatively basic (I think).

**Here is how I set the question up** which is correct based on the answer I was provided.

$$\neg \forall x (D(x) \to B(x))) \\\exists x (\neg B(x) \land T(x))) \\\therefore \exists x (D(x) \land T(x))))$$

**Steps** I took to reach valid:

$$\neg \forall x(D(x) \to B(x))) \\\neg \forall x (\neg D(x) \lor B(x))) \\ \exists x (D(x) \land \neg B(x)) \\D(a) \land \neg B(a) \\D(a) \\\exists x (\neg B(x) \land T(x)) \\\neg B(a) \land T(a) \\ D(a) \land T(a) \\\exists x (D(x) \land T(x)) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was using existential instantiation twice.
When I used

$$
D(a) \land \neg B(a)
$$
That is fine
But when I use for the second time, we cannot use the same variable a because we do not know if they are the same. It should look like
$$
\neg B(c) \land T(c)
$$

Then we cannot ensure that a and c are the same.

Answer (score 1):

As you already figured out, you cannot instantiate two different existentials with the same constant.

Indeed, this argument is *not* valid!

Counterexample:

Suppose the domain contains two objects, $a$ and $c$. Suppose that $a$ has property $D$, but not properties $B$ and $T$. Suppose that $c$ has property $T$, but not properties $B$ and $D$.

With that:

$a$ has property $D$, but not $B$, and so not all objects with property $D$ have property $B$. So, premise 1 is true.

$c$ has property $T$ but not $B$. So, premise 2 is true.

However, neither $a$ nor $c$ has both properties $D$ and $T$. So, the conclusion is false.

So, it is an invalid argument